# Unity detect click to 2d object without collider component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect gameObject with no collider under mouse.
I tried RayCast. But its work only for object with collider component.

Comment: Why dont you want to use a collider? Raycast is part of the physics and you will need a collider for the raycast to impact. Its a straightforward solution. 

Other thing you can do (as a computer graphics learning exercise) is check with the object mesh and it faces to thow a ray (a geometric line) in the forward direction of the camera and check if it collides.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add the collider.** But you can set it to `isTrigger` and avoid collisions.